# drop down bootstrap-select not working with theme Twenty Fourteen but works with other themes

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, themes

In wordpress, for a plugin, bootstrap-select is not working with theme Twenty Fourteen but works with other themes.

With theme : Twenty Fourteen
[bootstrap-select is not working with theme Twenty Fourteen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBkdB.png)

with all other themes (e.g Ascent) :
[works with other themes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US5Eo.png)

I guess it is because I miss a library but I cannot figure out which one ?
Here what I have added :

```
    /* CSS */
    wp_register_style('stern_bootstrapValidatorMinCSS', plugins_url('css/bootstrapValidator.min.css',__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('stern_bootstrapValidatorMinCSS');

    wp_register_style('stern_bootstrapValidatorCSS', plugins_url('css/bootstrapValidator.css',__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('stern_bootstrapValidatorCSS');        

    wp_register_style('stern_bootstrapbootstrap-selectMIN', plugins_url('css/bootstrap-select.min.css',__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('stern_bootstrapbootstrap-selectMIN'); 

    wp_register_style('stern_bootstrapbootstrap-select', plugins_url('css/bootstrap-select.css',__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('stern_bootstrapbootstrap-select');        

    wp_register_style('stern_bootstrap', plugins_url('css/bootstrap.min.css',__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('stern_bootstrap');        

    wp_register_style( 'stern-bootstrap', plugins_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stern-bootstrap');


    /* JS */
    wp_register_script('stern_bootstrapValidatorMin', plugins_url('js/bootstrapValidator.min.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('stern_bootstrapValidatorMin');

    wp_register_script('stern_bootstrapValidatorJS', plugins_url('js/bootstrapValidator.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('stern_bootstrapValidatorJS');        

    wp_register_script('stern_bootstrapselectMin', plugins_url('js/bootstrap-select.min.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('stern_bootstrapselectMin');  

    wp_register_script('stern_bootstrapselect', plugins_url('js/bootstrap-select.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('stern_bootstrapselect');                 


    wp_register_script('stern_bootstrapjs', plugins_url('js/bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('stern_bootstrapjs'); 

    wp_register_script('stern-bootstrapjs', plugins_url('/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'));      
    wp_enqueue_script('stern-bootstrapjs');
```

Comment: Do you hav any JS error in your console that tells you which library is missing?

Comment: Nope.. no Error in my console

Comment: Do you see _bootstrap-select.js_ call from the source when on Twenty Fourteen? If not, where did you added the enqueue scripts?